# javascript event for selectOneRadio

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a selectOneRadio component and I want to put an event on each selectItem inside it.

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="answer_type" layout="pageDirection" styleClass="required" value="#{editQuestionType.currentAnswerType}" immediate="true" onselect="onSelectAnswerType();" valueChangeListener="#{editQuestionType.answerTypeChanged}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{labels['editQuestionType.LineText']}" itemValue="0" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{labels['editQuestionType.MultipleLineText']}" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{labels['editQuestionType.Number']}" itemValue="2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{labels['editQuestionType.Date']}" itemValue="3" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{labels['editQuestionType.Time']}" itemValue="4" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{labels['editQuestionType.ChoiceList']}" itemValue="5" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{labels['editQuestionType.NomenclatorList']}" itemValue="6" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{labels['editQuestionType.Matrix']}" itemValue="7" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Below in the page code I am rendering some imputTexts. I want all the values previous inserted on these inputTexts corresponding to a ui:fragment to be deleted when I select one selectItem from selectOneRadio.

[image]

Let say we have this scenario:

1. I select the selectItem numbered with "1", then appear below some an inputText and I insert some text.
2. I select then the selectItem numbered with "2" and below appear the corresponding fragment with it's inputText where I insert some text.
3. I am selecting back the selectItem numbered with "1" and I want the value previously inserted on it's corresponding imputText to be deleted so I can type another text into it.

I have this function that gives to all components with the class onselectnoval the value emptyString:

```
function onSelectAnswerType() {
    $('.onselectnoval').val('');
}
```

All my inputTexts have this class.

What javascript event I should put on `selectOneRadio` (or inputTexts) to make it work?

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. I just called the function in the ui:fragment blocks.

Comment: There is no ui:fragment code in your question, so this Q/A combination is imo not of any importance to others. Please improve both the Q and A

Comment: if you read carefully, you would have seen this: "I want all the values previous inserted on these inputTexts corresponding to a ui:fragment to be deleted when I select one selectItem from selectOneRadio."

Comment: I read carefully.... the fact that you mention something in plain text (both in Q and A) does make it clear to others. It is at least totally not clear to me. (Off topic, you tag the question with jsf-2.2. Any reason you don't use ajax for solving this then?)